# How to start with new Facebook SDK for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've done quite some research on which ASP .NET Facebook SDK to use. Acording to this post (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx) old FacebookToolkit should not be used for new projects but instead we should use the all new and shiny [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

But he problem is that it lacks documentation, especially beginners examples for creating Facebook applications with Facebook SDK and WebForms:

1. How to start
2. Basic authentication examples
3. More examples...
4. Where did Facebook.Web.CanvasIFrameMasterPage  go from Toolkit ? :)

Comment: If you are new to web forms I would start by just learning web forms before trying to hook into the SDK.

Comment: Thanks, but I have quite some experience in ASP.NET. The problem I am having is lack of documentation for new Facebook SDK, beginners guide or examples.

Comment: Are you building a facebook iframe app or a connect website?

Comment: I am building iframe facebook application.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use webforms then you should really just revise the Facebook Authentication protocol. You are going to be using the Javascript SDK to do authentication, then just making your server side calls with the SDK, of which there are examples, usually something along the lines of:

```
var app = new FacebookApp();
// Get the user info from the Graph API
dynamic me = app.Api("/me");
var firstName = me.first_name;
```

If you want to use webforms with the SDK you are going to have to do some of the legwork yourself. If you continue to struggle with Authentication I can come up with an example for you.

In fact you can even do:

```
var app = new FacebookApp();
var authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(app);
authorizer.Perms = "stream_publish";
authorizer.Authorize(this.Request, this.Response);
```

Which redirects the user if they are not properly authenticated or don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: Thanks. What i am really looking for are some nice starter examples and best practices. I don't really want to struggle with .net authentication if Javascript SDK is preferred :). 
So far i've learned a few things but I still think that some basic examples and good practices would be helpful to lots of people. Maybe a list of useful links would be a great thing for a start.

Comment: So to clarify. You basically have to use the Javascript SDK and the Facebook C# SDK. They serve two separate purposes. The javascript does the client side stuff (most of the authentication) and the Facebook C# SDK is for server side stuff. Also, we are working on some samples and to improve our documentation. We will have more samples up in the next week or so.